# $\int_{\lambda+\varepsilon}^{+\infty}{d||E_{t}v||^{2}}=0$ implies $v\in \text{Im}1_{\{\lambda\}}(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Let $H$ be a non-negative definite self-adjoint operator in $L^{2}$ and $\{E_{t}\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ be its spectral resolution, that is $E_{t}=1_{(-\infty, t)}(H)$. Suppose that we have shown that for some $\lambda\geq 0$ and $v\in L^{2}$ that

$$\lambda\int_{\lambda}^{+\infty}{d||E_{t}v||^{2}}=\int_{\lambda}^{+\infty}{td||E_{t}v||^{2}}$$

Then why does it follow that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $$\int_{\lambda+\varepsilon}^{+\infty}{d||E_{t}v||^{2}}=0$$ and why does this imply that $v\in \text{Im}1_{\{\lambda\}}(H)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me set $\mu_v(A) = \|E(A)v\|^2$ for a Borel set $A$. You have
$$
0=\int_{\lambda}^\infty (1-t)\,d\mu_v(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\chi_{[\lambda,\infty)}(t)(1-t)\,d\mu_v(t) = \big(E([\lambda,\infty))(I-H)v,v\big).
$$
This *always* holds when $v$ has its support in $(-\infty,\lambda)$, i.e., $E((-\infty,\lambda))x = x$, showing that the second implication $v\in\operatorname{Im} E(\{\lambda\})$ is false. The first implication is true if $\lambda\ge 1$. But it is false if $\lambda < 1$. Let us go through the cases. But before, define $w = E([\lambda,\infty))v$. Then we have $((I-H)w,w) = 0$. Also set $X_\lambda = \operatorname{Im} E([\lambda,\infty))$.

$\lambda > 1$: For $u\in X_\lambda$ we have $(Hu,u)\ge\lambda\|u\|^2$. Since $w\in X_\lambda$, it follows that $0 = ((H-I)w,w) = (Hw,w)-\|w\|^2\ge(\lambda-1)\|w\|^2$, hence $w=0$. The first implication now easily follows.

$\lambda=1$: Then $((H-I)u,u)\ge 0$ for all $u\in X_\lambda$. If $T$ denotes the restriction of $H-I$ to $X_\lambda$, we have $(Tu,u)\ge 0$ for $u\in X_\lambda$, hence $T\ge 0$. Thus, $0 = ((H-I)w,w) = (Tw,w) = \|T^{1/2}w\|^2$, which implies $T^{1/2}w = 0$ and therefore $Tw = 0$, which means $Hw=w = \lambda w$. So, $E(\{\lambda\})w = w$ and whence $E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))v = E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))E([\lambda,\infty))v = E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))w = 0$.

$\lambda < 1$: A counterexample is $H|_{X_\lambda} = I|_{X_\lambda}$. Then $((I-H)w,w) = 0$, so your condition is satisfied, but $\int_{\lambda+\epsilon}^\infty\,d\mu_v(t) = \mu_v([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty)) = \mu_w([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty)) = \|w\|^2$.

Comment: Why is $E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))w = 0?$

Comment: $E(\{\lambda\})w = w$. Hence, $E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))w = E([\lambda+\epsilon,\infty))E(\{\lambda\})w = 0$ because the sets are disjoint.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are content with my answer, please check it.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question

Comment: So what? I answered it correctly and I am sure you can benefit from my answer to get the answer to your refined problem.

Comment: Do you do math only for such things?

Comment: I find your behaviour unbelievable. I spent a lot of time on thinking about your problem and writing it here. Are you actually aware of this?

Comment: Yes of course! I am really thankfull

Comment: Alright, but it is common policy on MSE to show your respect and thankfulness to acknowledge the answer by checking it.

Comment: You could open up another question, this time with the right assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Could you explain, why $\big(E([\lambda,\infty))(I-H)v,v\big)=0$ holds when $E((-\infty,\lambda))x = x$?

Comment: Because $E(\cdot)$ and $H$ commute and $E([\lambda,\infty))v = 0$.